# IBM Omnifind: How can I get several lines of text around hitting position?

Tags: search, full-text-search, search-engine

dear all

I'm implementing a solution with Omnifind, and one reqirement is for each "search hit", we should display several lines around hitting position to end user. Is this possible with Omnifind?

I'm using Omnifind Enterprise Edition ver 9.1

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a full-crawl and re-organizing index, it runs our "summary" field looks fine now. Cheers!